# Unable to access AKS application through custom subdomain

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns, azure-aks

I have successfully deployed an example application on my Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster using the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/master/docs/examples/aspnetapp.yaml
```

My AKS cluster is configured with Azure Application Gateway, and I have an Ingress resource that utilizes the Application Gateway with a Public IP address. I can access the web application using the IP address (http://20.93.56.72/), which works as expected. However, I encountered an issue when attempting to link the Public IP address to a custom DNS zone.

I have set up a subdomain and created an A record pointing to the working Public IP address. Nevertheless, I am unable to access the application using the subdomain. I have also tried creating an A record with an Alias record set pointing to the Public IP Azure Resource.

You can verify that the subdomains are pointing to the correct Public IP address (http://20.93.56.72/) using the following links:

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/mtest.6pack.dev
https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/test2.6pack.dev

Despite this, when I try to access the application using either mtest.6pack.dev or test2.6pack.dev, the application fails to load.

I am unsure of the cause of this issue. Do I need to make adjustments to the deployment configuration? Or should I add the A record to my DNS differently?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason is your domain `6pack.dev` is part of the [HSTS preload](https://hstspreload.org/?domain=6pack.dev) for browsers. The requests to insecure URL http://mtest.6pack.dev is going to be internally redirected to an https:// secure endpoint by the browser.

You don't seem to have the secure endpoint configured.